# Why isn’t result2.value = Yoshi (imposter) skulk?

Tags: javascript, yield

On the third assert I’m confused as to why imposter is returning Hanzo. I realize we redeclare imposter to equal Hanzo in our first assert but aren’t asserts evaluative and not supposed to result in expressions? Also imposter is a constant, how and when is imposter being reassigned?

```js
function assert(bool, msg) {
  if (!bool) {
    console.warn(msg);
  }
}

function* NinjaGenerator(action) {
  const imposter = yield("bob " + action);

  assert(imposter === "Hanzo",
    "The generator has been infiltrated");

  yield("Yoshi    (" + imposter + ") " + action);
}

const ninjaIterator = NinjaGenerator("skulk");

const result1 = ninjaIterator.next();
assert(result1.value === "bob skulk", "bob is skulking");

const result2 = ninjaIterator.next("Hanzo");
assert(result2.value === "Yoshi (Hanzo) skulk",
  "We have an imposter!");
```

I expect the last assert to pass as  “Yoshi (imposter) skulk“

Comment: *we redeclare imposter to equal Hanzo in our first assert* — that is not correct. The behavior has nothing to do with the `assert()` calls.

Comment: Also it's kind-of difficult to work with your code; *all* the quote characters are wrong.

Comment: OP: As far as I can tell your issue boils down to: *`const x = "foo";` Why is `x == "x"` not true?* Is that really what you're asking?

Comment: @melpomene No he is asking why `imposter` has been assigned with the value `Hanzo,` he probably didn't expect this assert to work. Pointy explains how the `const imposter` gets the assignment with Hanzo

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/198013/discussion-between-melpomene-and-icepickle).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because the `yield` is on the right-hand side of the assignment to `imposter`, the only value that variable ever has is `"Hanzo"`.  That is, the generator returns the first time before the assignment even happens.

Then you call

```
const result2 = ninjaIterator.next("Hanzo");
```

the `const` initialization for the `imposter` variable actually happens with the passed-in value `"Hanzo"`.  When the next `yield` is reached, the value of `imposter` is that value you see.

Understand that the initial call to `NinjaGenerator` does nothing but create the Iterator object and bind a value to the argument. Until the first call to `.next()`, nothing at all has happened. That first call will cause the  `const` initialization expression to be evaluated, etc.